# MACRO of library with path to avoid including a library twice in C?

Tags: c, include, conditional-compilation

How i can use `#ifndef` with a library like this `#include "../log/name.h"` to insert only once a library in a project with multiple source and header files.

Comment: `#ifndef` `#incldue` do not control if library is used or not by application. It just includes declaration of library symbols to current source. Your build manager is responsible for managing libraries (make/cmake/ninja/msvc project/xcode project/......). I smell [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header guards that's something like must have as it prevents processing it more than in one place. But if you really have to use this library header file. I would advise creating a kind of wrapper header.

```
#ifndef LOG_NAME_H_
#define LOG_NAME_H_
#include "../log/name.h"
#endif
```

It will be not preprocessed and reopened twice. You can try to pull request the library for missing header guard too.